# Fooling arbitrary symmetric functions

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, space-bounded, pseudorandomness

A distribution $\mathcal{D}$ is said to $\epsilon$-fool a function $f$ if $|E_{x\in U}(f(x)) - E_{x\in \mathcal{D}}(f(x))| \leq \epsilon$. And it is said to fool a class of functions if it fools every function in that class. 
It is known that $\epsilon$-biased spaces fool the class of parities over subsets. (see [Alon-Goldreich-Hastad-Peralta](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/p_aghp.html) for some nice constructions of such spaces). The question I want to ask is a generalization of this to arbitrary symmetric functions.

> **Question:** Suppose we take the class of arbitrary symmetric functions
>   over some subset, do we have
>   distribution (with small support) that
>   fools this class?

Some small observations:

- It is sufficient to fool exact thresholds ($\text{ETh}^S_k(x)$ is 1 if and only if $x$ has exactly $k$ ones amongst the indices in $S$). Any distribution that $\epsilon$-fools these exact thresholds will $n\epsilon$ fool all symmetric functions over $n$ bits. (This is because every symmetric function can be written as a real linear combination of these exact thresholds where the coefficients in the combination are either 0 or 1. Linearity of expectation then gives us what we want)
  A similar argument also works for general thresholds ($\text{Th}^S_k(x)$ is 1 if and only if $x$ has at least $k$ ones amongst the indices in $S$)
- There is an explicit construction of a distribution with support $n^{O(\log n)}$ via [Nisan's PRG for LOGSPACE](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~noam/sc.ps).
- Arbitrary $\epsilon$-biased spaces will not work. For example if $S$ is the set of all $x$ such that the number of ones in x is non-zero mod 3, this is actually $\epsilon$-biased for very small $\epsilon$ (from a [result of Arkadev Chattopadyay](http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/report/2006/107/)).   But clearly this does not fool the MOD3 function.

An interesting subproblem may be the following: suppose we just want to fool symmetric functions over *all n indices*, do we have a nice space? By the above observations, we just need to fool the threshold functions over $n$-bits, which is just a family of $n+1$ functions. Thus one can just pick the distribution by brute-force. But are there nicer examples of spaces that fool $\text{Th}^{[n]}_k$'s for every $k$?

Comment: Maybe this comment can help. Linial and Nisan's conjecture has recently been settled by Mark Braverman. The title of the paper is "Polylogarithmic independence fools AC^0 circuits". 


 http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mbraverm/Papers/FoolAC0v7.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a general solution to this problem has recently been given by
Parikshit Gopalan, Raghu Meka, Omer Reingold, and David Zuckerman,
see [Pseudorandom Generators for Combinatorial Shapes](http://eccc.uni-trier.de/report/2010/176/).

That paper handles an even more general setting, where the generator outputs $n$ $\log m$-bit blocks, which are then fed to arbitrary boolean functions, whose $n$ outputs are then fed to a boolean symmetric function.

A variety of sub-cases were already known; see for example [Pseudorandom Bit Generators That Fool Modular Sums](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.157.8574), [Bounded Independence Fools Halfspaces](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2009/016/), and [Pseudorandom Generators for Polynomial Threshold Functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4122). The first handles sums modulo $p$. The second and the third handle precisely the threshold tests you mention, however the error is not good enough to apply your reasoning to obtain a result for every symmetric function.

Comment: But Gopalan-Meka-Reingold-Zuckerman do not give an optimal PRG for inverse polynomial error right? For a constant $\varepsilon$, it is optimal though. 
Nevertheless, thank you very much for the pointer.

Comment: Indeed they don't. In general that's a difficult goal, and there are relatively few instances in the literature in which a logarithmic dependence on $\epsilon$ is achieved.